# Is re-compilation of rviz, after adding a module necessary?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I added a module in gazebo, it is working properly and not giving any error. Also i can see the rostopic but i am not able to see it in rviz. My question is that is it necessary to re compile the rviz. if yes, then how to compile it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10778/is-re-compilation-of-rviz,-after-adding-a-module-necessary?/) by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2011-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo and RViz are independent from each other, so no.

Apart from that, if you have some custom module that requires custom visualization, you would need to add that to rviz. Perhaps you can say a bit more explicit what you are doing?

For displaying sonars/IRs, check this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/1138/how-to-display-sonar-readings-in-rviz

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-04**:
The Sonar display is now present in Electric version of Ros. and also if one wants to display something in rviz, re compilation is necessary.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
I've never used the Range display mentioned in the linked post, but I'd guess you are doing something wrong. rviz communcates by messages, so your simulation should send out sensor_msgs/Range message and the rviz display should display them. You can test both independently with rostopic echo and pub

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-01**:
i am doing this,, studying the laser sensor which is already implemented in simulation (As i am too developing only in simulation) but i have two problems, rviz display and other my module is not able to get the value of the GetIRCount() function implemented in IRSensor.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
If I understand that correctly there is no real compiling, but the description is usually run through xacro and loaded in the param server. You can check how the pr2 does that.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-01**:
Onething more,, i need to know whether after creating the gazebo.xacro and urdf.xacro files and added it to base.gazebo.xacro, except that is it necessary to add it somewhere or compile it or only creation is enough.

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-08-01**:
Thanks for the reply,, i created a module that would for ir sensor, the topic is advertised (sensor_msgs::Range) but i am not able to see/load the topic (like the one LaserScan) in rviz. So i have to do some extra coding for that or i need to add something in xacro files.